# Exporting Object .obj with texture/ color

Tags: uv, export

I have made an object with color in shader editor and now need to export that. So that I have a png file with my textures and a obj file for my mesh. but i cant figure out how

Comment: File > Export > Wavefront (.obj). Make sure that write material is checked, this will generate the .mtl file with reference to the texture.

Comment: Just for the keywords: **You need to unwrap your model and bake the texture, if you want to get an image texture.**

Comment: How can I do that? I colored a lot of objects with shader editor